# Change the format of joining date to month-day,year sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

Change the format of  joining date to month-day,year for e.g. January 31,1992.

**Query**

```
select ename, to_char(joining_date,'Month DD,YYYY.') from emp_demo ;
```

**Error**

```
 'to_char' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

**Table emp_demo** format

```
joining_date
1992-01-31
```

Comment: Perhaps read the documentation? to_char is not a tsql function. Searching the internet will find many discussions about converting that to tsql if that is your goal.

Comment: Yoy say "joining date"; are you saying you're using the column that contains said date in the `JOIN` clause? If so, leave it as a Date and time data type; never store your dates as a `varchar` in your RDBMS. If it's simply for display purposes only, then the correct place tom change the display format is in the display layer.

Comment: thanks @Larnu....yes display layer is what i needed then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking to display your date in a given format (which is what `to_char()` does in Oracle).

In SQL Server, you can use `format()`:

```
select ename, format(joining_date, 'MMMM dd,yyyy.')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa57619795abe261aa4c1f4eede29f21)**:

```
select format(getdate(),'MMMM dd,yyyy.')
```

Yields:

```
May 04,2020.
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is pretty good about converting dates without a format.  Try:

```
select cast(joining_date as date)
from emp_demo;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5bbdf2f7c561a6f9dae0860b99c61970) is a db<>fiddle.

For the inverse transformation, you want to use `format()` with the format `'MMMM dd,yyyy'`.

Comment: I want the date format to change from 1992-01-31 to January 1, 1992

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor . . . . Why would you want to do that?  1992-01-31 is ISO standard format.  It is the best way to write the date.

Comment: It is needed as part of an interview question, hence asked

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.

```
Select Convert(Varchar(7), CONVERT(Varchar(20), getdate(), 100)) 
+ ', ' + Cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) as StatusOn

Select CAST(GETDATE() AS CHAR(3)) + ' ' + CONVERT(char(2), getdate(), 103) + ', '+ 
CONVERT(char(4), year(getdate())) as StatusOn
```

Output

[image]